# Error Handling with `do notation`?

Tags: haskell, error-handling

Given the data structure:

```
data CustomError = FooError | BarError deriving Show
```

And then two functions that perform `IO`:

```
foo :: IO (Either CustomError Int)
foo = return $ Right 100

bar :: IO (Either CustomError Int)
bar = return $ Left BarError
```

And a method that adds two `Either`'s.

```
add :: Either CustomError Int -> Either CustomError Int -> Either CustomError Int
add e1 e2 = (+) <$> e1 <*> e2
```

Lastly, a function that performs two `IO` actions, and then tries to apply `add` to their extracted `Right` values:

```
f :: IO (Either CustomError Int)
f = do
    x <- foo
    y <- bar
    return $ add x y
```

Running it shows:

```
λ: f
Left BarError
```

But, let's say that calling `foo` persists data to a database. If `foo` succeeds, but `bar` fails, then there will be irregular state. In other words, I want `f` to operate like a transaction - everything succeeds or nothing does.

I thought of doing something like:

```
fWithRecovery:: IO (Either CustomError Int)
fWithRecovery = do
    x      <- foo
    y      <- bar
    case y of (Right _)       -> return $ add x y
              (Left FooError) -> fmap Right recoverFoo
              (Left BarError) -> fmap Right recoverBar


recoverFoo :: IO Int
recoverFoo = do
    _ <- undefined -- clean up DB
    return 666     -- using an 'evil' value 
                   -- Note - I know using this value is horrible, but
                   --   I'm using for this simple example

recoverBar :: IO Int
recoverBar = do
    _ <- undefined -- clean up DB
    return 42      -- Note - I know using this value is horrible, but
                   --   I'm using for this simple example
```

But, I'm curious if there's an idiomatic way to handle roll-back for my `do notation` case.

Comment: Have you looked at using Software Transactional Memory or STM?

Comment: Non-related: That `Either` nested inside the `IO` could probably be better represented by the `ExceptT` monad transformer.

Comment: Hi @bheklilr - I have not looked at STM. Would you please show me how to apply it to this example?

Comment: @bheklilr: The idea is to use `TVar`s to collect the both results purely and then either commit them both to the database or completely roll back? Isn't it enough to just make `foo` and `bar` pure then? I also wonder if _"calling `foo` persists data to a database"_ means that the database's transaction control can be used.

Comment: Can you just throw a [`WriterT (Ap IO ())`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reducers-3.12.1/docs/Data-Semigroup-Applicative.html#t:Ap) into your monad transformer stack and use `tell` to accumulate roll-back actions?

Comment: could you please give an example, Daniel, for my question?